# how to configure raspberry pi wifi from iphone

Tags: wifi

I would like to be able to configure a raspberry pi 3 wifi with iphone
Is there any existing iPhone app that can do it?
I also would like to create such an application for iPhone.
What would be the right approach to do it? Using Bluetooth to communicate between iPhone and raspberry pi?
Are there any Bluetooth libraries and samples that I can use?

Comment: Does the Pi have Ethernet access?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the application, Pi Command, for the iPhone. It allows one to log into the Pi via SSH. At that point, you'll be able to configure the Pi WiFi through the command line.